# Does using a multivalued field in MS Access lock the table for other users

Tags: ms-access, locking, record, multivalue

I have a multi-user data entry application that I use for volunteer work to post survey data. I added 4 **multivalue** fields to one the versions and found that only one user could enter data via the form for that table at a time. I'd like to know if the **lock out** is related to the mutivalue field or to something else and if its due to the multivale field, is there a work around?

Comment: Are you using a split front-end/back-end configuration with each user having their own local copy of the front-end?